# how to change date string like "Tuesday , 12/12/2023" from English to Arabic in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I aim to dynamically convert date obtained from the server, initially in English, to be displayed in Arabic within my application. This includes translating not only textual content but also elements like weekday names and numbers.

I have attempted to address this requirement through the implementation of the following code snippet:

```dart
class ArabicDateWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ArabicDateWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.englishDateTimeString,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final String englishDateTimeString;

  @override
  _ArabicDateWidgetState createState() => _ArabicDateWidgetState();
}

class _ArabicDateWidgetState extends State<ArabicDateWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String formattedDate = "";
    try {
      DateTime date =
          DateFormat('EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy').parse(widget.englishDateTimeString);
       formattedDate = DateFormat('EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy', 'ar').format(date);
    } catch (e) {
      formattedDate = 'Invalid date format';
    }
    return Text(formattedDate);
  }
}
```

However, my efforts have been hampered by consistently encountering the return of the value "Invalid date format."

It is crucial for me to successfully convert and display the date in Arabic, encompassing not only general textual content but also elements such as weekday names and numerical values. Any guidance or suggested corrections to the code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way to do this in Flutter is to do it the same way as in Dart.

Answer (score 0):

Note that before doing any DateTime formatting for a particular locale, you must load the appropriate data by calling.

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
...
initializeDateFormatting('ar', null).then(formatDates);
```

Once the future returned from the initialization call returns, the formatting data is available.